# Error scaffolding add view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I updated mvc4 to mvc5 but when I try add a View, it throws the error:

> ---
>
> ### Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> ### Already referencing a newer version of 'jQuery'.
>
> ### OK

[image: Folder Scripts]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.7.2" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.20" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" />
  <package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="json2" version="1.0.2" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="1.7" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.5.4" requireReinstallation="True" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="2.0.11" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should update to the latest jQuery, version 1.11.3 if you need to support IE 6-8, version 2.1.4 otherwise.

Comment: I can't, other scripts crash.

Comment: You should update those as well. Old javascript libraries are more prone to security risks.

Comment: Solution was updating Jquery.Validation: Update-Package -id jQuery.Validation -version 1.8.1